# SQL - Column delimit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column like this

```
ID
--------
00012345
00067891
12345678
```

I need to eliminate 0's if there is any in the first 3 rows. What should I use as a query to achieve this?

I have no idea how to do this

Comment: _I need to eliminate 0's if there is any in the first 3_ So if you have a value `10067891` do you expect to get `167891`? What are your expected results?

Comment: What is the **datatype** of that column ??

Comment: @DaleK you added "rows" when editing. It's possible the OP meant "characters."

Comment: I think you'll find @marc_s added rows, not me.

Comment: `TRY_CAST(ID AS int)` maybe? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is number and want zeros removed, use the this code This code deletes all leading zeros but Code two only first 3 character delete

```
declare @m varchar(100)='00012345'
select try_cast(@m as int)
```

Otherwise, your input is not just a number or if you want it not to be deleted if there are two or one to zero, you can use the this code

```
declare @m varchar(100)='00012345'
select iif( SUBSTRING(@m, 1, 3)='000','' + SUBSTRING(@m, 4, len(@m)-3),@m)
--result:12345


declare @m varchar(100)='00A147474'
select iif( SUBSTRING(@m, 1, 3)='000','' + SUBSTRING(@m, 4, len(@m)-3),@m)
--result:00A147474

declare @m varchar(100)='00147474'
select iif( SUBSTRING(@m, 1, 3)='000','' + SUBSTRING(@m, 4, len(@m)-3),@m)
--result:00A147474

declare @m varchar(100)='12345678'
select iif( SUBSTRING(@m, 1, 3)='000','' + SUBSTRING(@m, 4, len(@m)-3),@m)
--result:12345678
```